# Assign a CheckBox LinkedCell to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a list of jobs as a series of CheckBoxes so they can be cleared as completed. My code searches for the first 10 jobs that meet a certain criteria and then assigns the job title as the check box caption, this is displayed in a userform. I want to link a cell in the same row but I don't know how it should be written.

If I comment out the bit where I try to assign a `LinkedCell` then everything works. I've read lots of answers to these sorts of questions and I can see that in an ideal world the linked cell format would be `"A1"` but I don't know how to rewrite `srcWS.Cells(cardRow, defectClosed).Address`, so it can be used

```
Set srcWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each contr In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
        For cardRow = startCount To srcWS.Range(staffID & srcWS.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            If srcWS.Cells(cardRow, defectDesc).Value <> "" Then
                contr.Caption = srcWS.Cells(cardRow, defectCount).Value & "   " & srcWS.Cells(cardRow, defectDesc).Value _
                & "   " & srcWS.Cells(cardRow, taskcardID).Value
                contr.LinkedCell = srcWS.Cells(cardRow, defectClosed).Address
                startCount = cardRow + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I **get an error** saying `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: You need the sheetname, the Address only provides the range.

Comment: Isn't the sheetname specified by 'Set srcWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")?

Comment: Actually, I just saw the `Me.` portion of your code, you are working with a UserForm, checkboxes on UserForms do not have a LinkedCell property. Edit: A LinkedCell is used on a CheckBox within a Sheet of Excel because is the easy way to know if it's checked or not without involving VBA. If you are working with a UserForm, you will 100% be working with VBA, so you dont need the LinkedCell property because you can just write TRUE or FALSE on any cell with VBA after checking the CheckBox status.

Comment: Set the `Tag` property of the checkbox to the address of the cell it needs to link to: as Ricardo notes though, you'll need to handle updating the sheet using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo A and Tim Williams, you absolute legends!! Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction. I set

```
contr.Tag = cardRow
```

and then wrote

```
srcWS.Cells(CheckBox1.Tag, defectClosed).Value = "Closed"
```

Whenever that checkbox is clicked.